# How does SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY'] in Django work?

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean, secret-key

I have my hardcoded `SECRET_KEY` in my `settings.py` file locally and want to put this file onto my live Digital Ocean server. If I just replace `SECRET_KEY = 'xxx-xxx-xxx'` with `SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']` will it work? I'm assuming I have to do something else to actually get my local `SECRET_KEY` on there.

Comment: define an environment variable called SECRET_KEY with your secret key.

Comment: How to define an environment variable for a process you're presumably going to run as a service depends on how process supervision is done on your specific operating system. For every one of systemd, runit, Upstart, daemontools, launchd, &c., it'll be different. As such, this isn't really a Python question *or* a Django question, but an operating-system-level configuration question.

Comment: Digital Ocean has a tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps, but it's really covering the high-level portable basics, rather than anything that's specific and actionable; I'm assuming that's because they support multiple guest operating systems, so their documentation can't make assumptions about which one you're using either.

Comment: I'm assuming you can install whatever python packages you like?  I think it's a good practice for any project with secure information to use `python-decouple`.  You reference variables stored in a `.env` location.   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-decouple

Comment: Do I declare the environment variable in my gunicorn config (`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`) or somewhere else? @arunkumar

Comment: @Zorgan not sure about the exact syntax for gunicorn config, but yes, you should be able to define it there.

Answer (score 1):

You just got to use [django-environ](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-environ). They even have a simple tutorial on the package page. Best part: It is inspired by the [12factor app](https://www.12factor.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I just was running into same problem and it's just fixed from a minute ago i'm on windows so if you are too just follow this video super fast super easy :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IolxqkL7cD8

video title:
Python Quick Tip: Hiding Passwords and Secret Keys in Environment Variables (Windows)

he has some explanation on about it in mac and linux also just search for:

Python Quick Tip: Hiding Passwords and Secret Keys in Environment Variables mac and linux

Answer (score 0):

For the secret key and other values to be available within your venv, you should specify them in your environment's postactivate hook and unset in the predeactivate hook. I know it sounds scary, but you can find good explanation in the TaskBuster tutorial by Marina Mele.
[Link](http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/settings-different-environments-version-control#django-security)